# xamarin not saving image to mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, xamarin, base64

im am trying to save a picture to my mysql database using base64string. i can take a pic or open he pic from my gallery and show it on screen. from there i try to save it. it saves all data except my image.
i have stepped through my code to verify that it was converted to base64string but the db shows blob - 0' i am using a medium blob.
if i convert online using a base64 converter then doing a save through an sql using phopmyadmin statement it works. but from my app no go.

```
private byte[] _picData;
    if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
    {
        if (requestCode == 2)
        {
            Uri selectedImage = data.Data;

            Bitmap mBitmap = null;
            try
            {
                mBitmap = Media.GetBitmap(this.ContentResolver, selectedImage);
                photo.SetImageURI(selectedImage);

                Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
                MemoryStream newStream = new MemoryStream();
                bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Webp, 100, newStream);
                _picData = newStream.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Java.IO.IOException e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
            }

        }



        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://www.sbmgroup.ca/test/biteboard/meal.php");
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
        if (_type.Equals("takePicture") || _type.Equals("openPicture"))
        {
            parameters.Add("type", "add");
            parameters.Add("user_id", _user_id.ToString());
            parameters.Add("meal", mealType);
            parameters.Add("scribble", scribble.Text);
            parameters.Add("feeling", _feelValue.ToString());
            parameters.Add("taste", _tasteValue.ToString());
            parameters.Add("date", date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"));
            parameters.Add("picture", Convert.ToBase64String(_picData));
            client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);
            client.UploadValuesCompleted += Client_UploadValuesCompleted;
        }
```

my php

```
<?php
    include("ConnectionInfo.php");
    global $type;
    global $id;
    global $user_id;
    global $meal;
    global $scribble;
    global $date;
    global $taste;
    global $feeling;
    global $picture;
    global $mealArray;

    $type = $_REQUEST['type'];
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
    $meal = $_REQUEST['meal'];
    $scribble = $_REQUEST['scribble'];
    $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
    $dateLike = "{$_REQUEST['date']}%";
    $taste = $_REQUEST['taste'];
    $feeling = $_REQUEST['feeling'];
    $picture = $_REQUEST['picture'];
    $mealArray = array();

    if ($type === "add")
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO meals (user_id,meal,comment,date,taste,feeling,mealPic) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        $stmt->bind_param('isssiib',$user_id,$meal,$scribble,$date,$taste,$feeling,$picture);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();
        $newId = $conn->insert_id;
        echo $newId;
    }
```

i have looked through similar questions with no help.

Comment: Because you send it as `pic` and read as `picture`...

Comment: that wasnt it, they were both pic before same result but just to be diligent i tested your answer to no avail. code updated here.